# Play and Pause audio with the same button please

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and just play, but I want to play and pause with the same button (image) and I don't know what I need to add, what I need to do? Help me please

```
        <script>
          function play(){
               var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
               audio.play();
                         }
           </script>

        <input type="image" id= "Portada1" src= "https://66.media.tumblr.com/dc48784826909289a58767fed35ba421/tumblr_pu7p4w8Jai1yrcbyio1_1280.jpg" alt ="Portada del sencillo Tim McGraw de Taylor Swift." onclick="audio.play  ()">


        <audio id="audio" src="Audio/Teardrops On My Guitar.mp3" ></audio>

         </body>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to attach your image

Answer (score 1):

- Introduce global boolean variable
- Change it on button tap
- Play or pause depending on this variable

```
// on top of your JS file
let isPlaying = false;
// your function
function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  if (isPlaying) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.stop();
  }
  isPlaying = !isPlaying;
}
```

Comment: `isPlaying  = !isPlaying` is just a simple Boolean that **eventually toggles** two states of `audio` correctly. The state is not determined whether `audio` is playing or not  but rather that the button was clicked. This is clearly evident when the button is initially clicked and nothing happens until the second click. More importantly, there is no such method called `.stop()` for media elements..

Answer (score 1):

`<input type='image'>` are actually fancy submit buttons which full functionality is possible when nested within a `<form>`, but for OP's purposes, a `<button>` with a `background-image` is not only semantically accurate but also ensures there will be no possible side-effects.

```
  <button type='button'></button>

  button { background: url(https://example.com/path/to/image.jpg)....}
```

To toggle `.play()` and `.pause()` methods on an audio object, either use

```
  if (audio.paused || audio.ended) {... //if audio is not playing
```

OR

```
  if (audio.playing) {... // if audio is playing
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = player;

function player(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;
  clicked.classList.toggle('playing');
  const song = document.querySelector('audio');
  if (song.paused || song.ended) {
    song.play();
  } else {
    song.pause();
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background: url(https://www.hardwoodandhollywood.com/pop-culture-spin/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2015/02/florencemachine.jpg)no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 124px;
  height: 86px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid rgba(158, 127, 103, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 4px 6px 7px rgba(158, 127, 103, 0.6);
  border-radius: 20%;
}

button:hover {
  border: 3px solid rgba(158, 127, 103, 1);
}

.playing {
  border: 3px solid rgba(58, 127, 203, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 4px 6px 7px rgba(58, 127, 203, 0.6);
}

.playing:hover {
  border: 3px solid rgba(58, 127, 203, 1);
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0
}
```

```html
<button type='button'></button>
<audio src='https://gldrv.s3.amazonaws.com/av/Florence_and_the_Machine-Dog_%20Days_are_Over.mp3'></audio>
```